# Javascript not working on Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, iframe

#### I no longer need the answer to this question, but I'm still curious if anyone would like to answer it.

I'll be simple. The code below doesn't do anything on Chrome for Android as far as I can tell. The iframe refuses to be resized. It works on every major desktop browser, however. There is no cross-domain blocking because of the previous sentence and both the page and the iframe source are in the same folder on the same web server.

```
function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}

function setIframeHeight(myiframeid) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(myiframeid);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px";
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 5+"px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

(function(run){
    for (i=0;i<frames.length; i++) {
        var f1 = document.getElementsByTagName('myiframename')[i];
        if(!f1 && window.addEventListener && !run){
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', arguments.callee, false);
            return;
        }
        if(!f1){setTimeout(arguments.callee, 300); return;}
        f2 = f1.cloneNode(false);
        f1.src = 'about: blank';
        f2.frameBorder = '0';
        f2.allowTransparency = 'yes';
        f2.scrolling = 'no';
        f1.parentNode.replaceChild(f2, f1);
    }
})();
```

The iframe code is follows:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="200" id="myframeid" marginheight="0" name="myframename" onload="javascript:setIframeHeight(this.id);" scrolling="no" src="http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Joel I have been working on webviews in fragments for about a 4 months now, what are you trying to do I may be able to help

Comment: I'm all ears....or eyes....or you know.

Comment: @MarkGilchrist Did you forget about this? I need answers.

Comment: I did, when you say it doesn't work properly what exactly do you mean

Comment: @MarkGilchrist I edited the post for clarification. It simply does nothing as far as I can tell. The iframe does not resize at all on Chrome for Android.